# How to go about uncaching data only when the data changes?

Tags: javascript, xml, xhtml

I have a SCORM (eLearning) web app (javascript/html) that loads content from xml files via ajax requests. These xml files are generated from a CMS (Content management system) built from drupal, so the content changes every so often.

Since the content (text, images) changes infrequently I want the data to be cached in the users browser most of the time, but not when the content is updated. Currently I have a cachebuster string that gets updated when any content does and I use that string in the url when loading any of these files (eg. path/to/content.xml?uncache=RANDOMSTRING).

However, now I have run into a problem where Firefox is getting stuck in a redirect loop (because of the cachebuster string?) on a clients server. So I did some searching and read that it's not the best method of uncaching data.

Does anyone have experience in this arena? Would like to hear your thoughts on the matter..

EDIT (more info): The webapp cannot communicate to the host server apart from the SCORM API which is limited to data about the app. It may not be able to communicate to a third party server as it could be within an intranet too. Basically, the host server loads the index file, then my app does it's thing. It loads a "structure file" which has info about the app and has the updated cachebuster string (essentially this is a version string as mentioned by dferraro below).

Answer (score 0):

You could track a 'version number' or token on the client.. Then have a timer that fires every so often to pull the latest 'version number'. If it changed, then re-fresh all the data. This would be a 'polling' method and could very well be the best solution for your needs.

If your needs require a more robust solution than the polling method, you could take a 'push' approach. Depending on your stack you could use some smarter technology to have your server automatically notify your client code of updates. Examples of this include [PokeIn](http://www.pokein.com/Help/Documentation.aspx), [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) or even [Service Broker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx).

Comment: The SCORM package is an independent application than can only communicate with the host server via a limited api (will update question). I guess polling is what I'm doing with the cachebuster string right. That only gets updated when the content does. How would you go about re-caching on the ajax requests?

Comment: so the issue is only with the querystring & redirects? Instead of query string, can you track the cachebuster using sessionStorage? http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/07/21/introduction-to-sessionstorage/

Comment: Unfortunately would not work as the user is accessing the webapp over days/weeks/months, so they would be logging in and out in between uses. 
However, cookies could be an option. The script could check last known version in the cookie and send no-cache headers in the ajax request if it didn't match.

Comment: curious what you wound up doing here. Did the cookie work for you>?